# Group data.frame by column and select number of rows based on numeric vector

Tags: r, select, dplyr, grouping, rows

Let's say I have got a data.frame like the following:

```
df = read.table(text = 'A   B
                11 98
                11 87
                11 999
                11 22
                12 34
                12 34
                12 44
                12 98
                17 77
                17 67
                17 87
                17 66
                33 6
                33 45
                33 12
                33 10', header = TRUE)
```

I need to group `df` by col `A` and select only a given number of rows based on the following vector:

```
n_rows = c(2, 3, 4, 2)
```

So that the first group will have only 2 rows (no matter their order), the second group 3 rows, etc...

Here my expected output:

```
            A   B
            11 98
            11 87
            12 34
            12 34
            12 44
            17 77
            17 67
            17 87
            17 66
            33 6
            33 45
```

I tried to do the trick with `dplyr` by doing the following:

```
  df %>% 
  group_by(A) %>% 
  top_n(n = n_rows, wt =B)
```

but I got the following error:

> Error: `n` must be a scalar integer

Any suggestion?

thanks

Comment: If the `wt` is `B`, then wouldn't 999 be the value instead of 87?  This is based on the usage of `top_n`.  If you only need the first two values, it is fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a possibility, splitting first the `data.frame` then using `map2`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purr)
df %>% split(.$A) %>%
  map2_dfr(n_rows,head)

#     A  B
# 1  11 98
# 2  11 87
# 3  12 34
# 4  12 34
# 5  12 44
# 6  17 77
# 7  17 67
# 8  17 87
# 9  17 66
# 10 33  6
# 11 33 45
```

If order doesn't matter you don't need `top_n`, `head` works just fine (and faster), else just replace `head` with `top_n`.

**EDIT:**

Here is also a tidy solution, a few characters longer but maybe more satisfying as you don't separate things of the same "kind" but rather work completely inside of the `data.frame` (same output).

```
df %>% nest(B) %>% 
  mutate(data = map2(data,n_rows,head)) %>%
  unnest
```

Comment: I guess the OP made a wrong choice with `top_n`.  Or else, you may want to `arrange` it

Comment: Right I'll clarify

Comment: thank you to all. that's the option that best works for me.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an option with `top_n`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
   split(., .$A) %>% 
   map2_df(., n_rows, ~ top_n(., .y, wt = .$B))
```

---

If we are not looking for `top_n`, then another option is `slice`

```
df %>% 
   group_by(A) %>% 
   nest(B) %>% 
   mutate(newcol = map2(data, n_rows, ~ .x %>% slice(seq(.y)))) %>%
   select(-data) %>%
   unnest
```

Answer (score 3):

Another base R option,

```
do.call(rbind, Map(function(x, y) x[seq(y),], split(df, df$A), n_rows))
```

which gives,

> ```
>       A  B
> 11.1  11 98
> 11.2  11 87
> 12.5  12 34
> 12.6  12 34
> 12.7  12 44
> 17.9  17 77
> 17.10 17 67
> 17.11 17 87
> 17.12 17 66
> 33.13 33  6
> 33.14 33 45
> ```

Comment: A similar method is `do.call(rbind, Map(function(x, y) head(df[df$A == x,], y), unique(df$A), n_rows))`.

Answer (score 2):

In base `R`, you can do something like:

```
df2 <- data.frame()

for (i in seq_along(unique(df$A))) {
   df2 <- rbind(df2, df[df$A == unique(df$A)[i], ][1:n_rows[i], ])
}

> df2
    A  B
1  11 98
2  11 87
5  12 34
6  12 34
7  12 44
9  17 77
10 17 67
11 17 87
12 17 66
13 33  6
14 33 45
```